# How to do univariate outlier treatment dynamically

Tags: r, outliers

Suppose i have the following data:

```
df<-iris[,1:2]# taking only 2 numeric columns
```

Now i want to do univariate outlier test where in I define outlier as any data greater than 1.5 * IQR.Then After identification of any outlier if any, I cap the outlier to either 95% on the upper end or 5% on the lower end as shown below:

```
a <- df$Sepal.Length
qnt_a <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.25,0.75))
caps_a <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.05,0.95))
H_a <- 1.5 * IQR(a)
a[a < (qnt_a[1] - H_a)] <- caps_a[1]
a[a > (qnt_a[1] + H_a)] <- caps_a[2]
df$Sepal.Length <- a
```

Similarily i do for other remaining numeric variable:

```
b <- df$Sepal.Width
qnt_b <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.25,0.75))
caps_b <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.05,0.95))
H_b <- 1.5 * IQR(b)
b[b < (qnt_b[1] - H_b)] <- caps_b[1]
b[b > (qnt_b[1] + H_b)] <- caps_b[2]
df$Sepal.Width <- b

df
```

I would like help in formulating a loop where i can do the identification as well as capping of the outliers across all numeric variables in a dataframe instead of doing variable by variable......

Comment: Wow, what a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to make it a function and apply it, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(a){
  qnt_a <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.25,0.75))
  caps_a <- quantile(a, probs = c(0.05,0.95))
  H_a <- 1.5 * IQR(a)
  a[a < (qnt_a[1] - H_a)] <- caps_a[1]
  a[a > (qnt_a[1] + H_a)] <- caps_a[2]
  return(a)
}

df[] <- lapply(df, f1)
```